# refreshing Div with php code inside?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to refresh a div every x seconds using the code bellow:

the div only holds a small timezone PHP code inside of it.

this is the code i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#holder').load('<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
echo  'Current Time In Australia:' . date('H:i:s.A') . PHP_EOL;
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
echo date('d/m/Y', time());
?>').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

The div id is holder and it is like this:

```
<div id="holder" style="color:#fff; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:44px; font-weight:bold;"><?php
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
echo  'Current Time In Australia:' . date('H:i:s.A') . PHP_EOL;
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
echo date('d/m/Y', time());
?></div>
```

unfortunately the code above doesn't refresh the Div at all.

is there anything else that I need to do or am I missing something?

Comment: jquery .load loads a url not a snippet, put that php in a file and load the file instead

Answer (score 2):

get-date.php:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
echo 'Current Time In Australia:' . date('H:i:s.A') . PHP_EOL;
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()); // not sure what this is doing!
echo date('d/m/Y', time());
```

New script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
    $('#holder').load('get-date.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

Or as a one pager, put this above all other code

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['show_date']))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
    echo 'Current Time In Australia:' . date('H:i:s.A') . PHP_EOL;
    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()); // not sure what this is doing!
    echo date('d/m/Y', time());
    exit;
}
?>
```

Then use this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
        $('#holder').load('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?show_date').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

Comment: is there anyway i can do this in the same page? i.e. not using get-date.php ?

Comment: No. PHP is parsed before rendering a page. After the rendering is complete u can't just re-execute code

Comment: Updated my answer, hope that helps

Comment: As DarkBee says you can't re-exectute code, you have to load it at some point so I would prefer to separate it out into another file personally

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx - the name of the variable used to tell the 3rd snippet that we want to .... show the date.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx `?show_date` is a `$_GET` parameter (in PHP) it's just used to trigger the if condition

Answer (score 0):

PHP is Server Side Language, it wont work in Client Side..
 you are trying to display time i hope..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {



// Create two variable with the names of the months and days in an array
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ]; 
var dayNames= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]

// Create a newDate() object
var newDate = new Date();
// Extract the current date from Date object
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
// Output the day, date, month and year   
$('#Date').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + " " + newDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());

setInterval( function() {
    // Create a newDate() object and extract the seconds of the current time on the visitor's
    var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
    // Add a leading zero to seconds value
    $("#sec").html(( seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + seconds);
    },1000);

setInterval( function() {
    // Create a newDate() object and extract the minutes of the current time on the visitor's
    var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    // Add a leading zero to the minutes value
    $("#min").html(( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes);
    },1000);

setInterval( function() {
    // Create a newDate() object and extract the hours of the current time on the visitor's
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    // Add a leading zero to the hours value
    $("#hours").html(( hours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + hours);
    }, 1000);   
});

</script>
```

CSS
    /*-----------------------------*/

```
 .clock_home a{
        font-size:18px;
    }
    a:hover,a:focus{
        text-decoration: none!important;
    }
    .clock_home{
        float:right;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .clock {

        height:25px;
        width: 260px;
        margin: 10px 20px  auto auto;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        color: #0088CC;
    }

    #Date {
        font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:16px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 15px;
        /*text-shadow: 0 0 5px #00c6ff;*/
    }

    .clock ul {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .clock ul li {
        display: inline;
        text-align: center;
        float:left;
        font-size:16px;
        font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        /*text-shadow: 0 0 5px #00c6ff;*/
    }

    #point {
        position: relative;
        -moz-animation: mymove 1s ease infinite;
        -webkit-animation: mymove 1s ease infinite;
    }

    /* Simple Animation */
    @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        0% {opacity: 1.0;
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #00c6ff;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        text-shadow: none;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1.0;
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #00c6ff;
    }   
    }

    @-moz-keyframes mymove {
        0% {
            opacity: 1.0;
            text-shadow: 0 0 20px #00c6ff;
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 0;
            text-shadow: none;
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 1.0;
            text-shadow: 0 0 20px #00c6ff;
        };
    }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="clock">
            <div id="Date"></div>
              <ul>
                  <li id="hours"></li>
                  <li id="point">:</li>
                  <li id="min"></li>
                  <li id="point">:</li>
                  <li id="sec"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Refreshing the whole page is quite dirty.. Use ajax instead

Comment: i do not want to refresh the whole page. i need to refresh only a Div inside of the page.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot use javascript for the entire process. i need to use my own php in combination with javascript. a heads up: i know php is server side and javascript is client side. i think you've missed the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0;
var countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p.countdown").html("Changes Saved, Redirecting..");
    if (count == 0) {
      clearInterval(countdown);

        $.post("get-date.php",{},function(data,success){$('#target_div').html(data);})
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
```